# How to get google map markers to bounce on hover of result list

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, mouseover, onhover

I have a simple map with a filter and the data for markers is pulled from a fusion table. I also have a “results list” that populates with the search results. I am simply trying to get the markers to bounce when I hover on the corresponding address in the result list. 
Sounds simple enough, but my map does not have hard coded markers in my HTML or JS files, they are static based on the search criteria and the locations are pulled from the fusion table. 
I have looked all over the internet and have found very little documentation about working with the “result list” in Google maps API v3.

Here is what I have tried to add to my code: 
// make a .hover event

```
 $('#results_list .addrMarkerImage').hover(
      // mouse in
      function () {
        var index = $('#results_list .addrMarkerImage').index(this);
        addrMarkerImage[index].setIcon(highlightedIcon());
      },
      // mouse out
      function () {
        var index = $('results_list .addrMarkerImage').index(this);
        addrMarkerImage[index].setIcon(normalIcon());
      }

    );
```

And this:

//Bounce marker on list hover

```
 $('#markers_info .marker').hover(
function(b){var b=MapsLib.setAnimation(),

    $(".results_list").on("mouseenter",".displayList",
function(){var c=$(this).data("lat"),
b=a.getMarker(c,true);
b.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);return});
$(".map-list").on("mouseleave",".displayList",
},
);
```

I’m not trying to do brain surgery here, I just want the markers to bounce on hover of the appropriate item in the results list. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Currently my efforts have either (had no effect at all ) or (crashed the map page) By “crashed” I mean that the map, markers and result list simply did not show up at all.

If needed, I can add the code for my index.html and maps_lib.js files in a reply.

Thank you in advance for any help you could offer.

Here is where I call the function to display the results in a list box. 
    //DISPLAY RESULTS FUNCTION

```
MapsLib.prototype.getList = function(whereClause) {
    var self = this;
    var selectColumns = 'type, title, address, Column1, phone ';

    self.query({ 
      select: selectColumns, 
      where: whereClause 
    }, function(response) { 
      self.displayList(response);

     });
  },

  MapsLib.prototype.displayList = function(json) {
    var self = this;

    var data = json['rows'];
    var template = '';

    var results = $('#results_list');
    results.hide().empty(); //hide the existing list and empty it out first

    if (data == null) {
      //clear results list
      results.append("<li><span class='lead'>No results found</span></li>");

    }
    else {
      for (var row in data) {
        template = "\
          <div class='row-fluid item-list'>\
            <div class='span12'>\
              <strong>" + data[row][0] + "</strong>\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][1] + "\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][2] + "\
              <br />\
              " + data[row][3] + "\
               <br />\
              " + data[row][4] + "<br>\
            </div>\
          </div>";
        results.append(template);
      }
    }
    results.fadeIn();

          var results = $('#results_list');
 };
```

Comment: Set up a working jsfiddle or something to make this easier to answer, please

Comment: Okay, I created a jsfiddle. It's a little crude looking, it's the first one I created so I am not sure if I did it correctly.  Here is the link for it - https://jsfiddle.net/pailwriter/9tkqsesy/2/

Comment: As far as I can tell the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pailwriter/9tkqsesy/2/) doesn't work at all. Please provide sample data to expose your problem as well.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure why it's not running in jsfiddle. copying the code to individual files using the naming conventions (index.html, maps_lib.js and custom.css) and saving them in a folder will get the working model when you open the index.html in google chrome.

Comment: Look at the javascript console, address the errors there. (for one thing include jquery, and another, remove all the references to external files that don't exist)

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9tkqsesy/6/) shows a map.  Please provide instructions on how to display markers and the results list that you want the marker to bounce when hovered over and/or fix it to exhibit your issue.

Comment: Okay, I guess I need a crash course in jsfiddle first. I simply copied my HTML, JavaScript, and CSS pages to the appropriate boxes and added the external sources like bootstrap. It works fine on my computer but not in jsfiddle.